# Removing specific word in paragraph and modifying first word after it with JS & regex?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

With use of JavaScript/jQuery and RegEx I would like to remove all instances of the word 'Integer' from paragraph below and first word after the deleted word should be capitalized.

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam elit
> massa, maximus in turpis vel, viverra iaculis nisl. Nullam pulvinar mi
> eu metus posuere, a porta ligula feugiat. **Integer** quis nunc neque.
> Etiam sollicitudin diam in dolor sagittis pellentesque. Nunc placerat
> sollicitudin purus. Proin mattis, quam sit amet pellentesque blandit,
> urna erat mollis sapien, et vestibulum nunc mi sed orci. **Integer** ligula
> tellus, maximus id orci quis, euismod consequat nulla.

My attempt so far for removing desired word:

```
var modified = $(".paragraph").html();

modified = modified.replace(/Integer\s/g, '');
```

But after that I don't know how to dynamically access the next word (from above example text word: 'quis' and 'ligula') and set it to be capitalized. One note: the word that needs to be deleted is always the same, but word after is always different.

Comment: Are the `*` present in your actual string? Maybe `Integer\s+([a-z])` would suffice, then something like `, uppercase_js_function('$1'));`

Comment: Sorry about the ```*```, it's a "residue" from copy/pasting. I'll look into your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be sure of getting a capitalized word every time after removing **Integer**, use the following:

```js
modified = modified.replace(/Integer\s+(\w)/g, function(fullMatch, capturedGroup) { 
     return capturedGroup.toUpperCase(); 
});
```

**Note**: This would even match Integer followed by *Capitalised* words. If you want to select only instances of Integer followed by lowercase words, then use `[a-z]` instead of `\w` in the above regex.

Comment: Thank you, this answer is all I needed. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Not a regex but this one liner can fulfil your purpose.

```
let str = `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam elit 
massa, maximus in turpis vel, viverra iaculis nisl. Nullam pulvinar mi eu metus 
posuere, a porta ligula feugiat. Integer quis nunc neque. Etiam sollicitudin diam 
in dolor sagittis pellentesque. Nunc placerat sollicitudin purus. Proin mattis, 
quam sit amet pellentesque blandit, urna erat mollis sapien, et vestibulum nunc 
mised orci. Integer ligula tellus, maximus id orci quis, euismod consequat nulla.`;
```

```
str.split(/Integer\ /g).map(part=>{return part.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + part.substr(1)}).join("")
```

Answer (score 0):

there is maybe a way with replace directly, but i would do it like this maybe:

```
let textResult;
do {
    textResult = /Integer\s(.)/gs.exec(modified);
    if (!textResult || !textResult[1]) {
        textResult = null;
        continue;
    }
    modified = modified.replace('Integer ' + textResult[1], textResult[1].toUpperCase());
} while (!!textResult);
```